# Get all local groups members and account status - locked and disabled

Tags: powershell

I am struggling to pull out from hundred of servers information into Excel spreadsheet about all existing local groups including their members with account status.

Spent several hours trying to parse information from various tools and combine them back but I surrender. Using PowerShell will good enough for my purpose, however I'm new to this scripting language and have a lack of time for learning this particular case so I would ask some expert for help here. I found many codes but no such fitted my needs.

I have server list - **servers.lst** - and need **output into csv file** following:

**server name - domain/local group name (in format domain\name) - account name (in format domain\name) - group/user - disabled - locked out - lockout date**

Found a script which almost fits my needs from Piotr Lewandowski (Thanks for this!!!)

```
<#
===================================================================================  
DESCRIPTION:    Function enumerates members of all local groups (or a given group). 
If -Server parameter is not specified, it will query localhost by default. 
If -Group parameter is not specified, all local groups will be queried. 

AUTHOR:     Piotr Lewandowski 
VERSION:    1.0  
DATE:       29/04/2013  
SYNTAX:     Get-LocalGroupMembers [[-Server] <string[]>] [[-Group] <string[]>] 

EXAMPLES:   

Get-LocalGroupMembers -server "scsm-server" | ft -AutoSize

Server      Local Group          Name                 Type  Domain  SID
------      -----------          ----                 ----  ------  ---
scsm-server Administrators       Administrator        User          S-1-5-21-1473970658-40817565-21663372-500
scsm-server Administrators       Domain Admins        Group contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-512
scsm-server Guests               Guest                User          S-1-5-21-1473970658-40817565-21663372-501
scsm-server Remote Desktop Users pladmin              User  contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-1272
scsm-server Users                INTERACTIVE          Group         S-1-5-4
scsm-server Users                Authenticated Users  Group         S-1-5-11



"scsm-dc01","scsm-server" | Get-LocalGroupMembers -group administrators | ft -autosize

Server      Local Group    Name                 Type  Domain  SID
------      -----------    ----                 ----  ------  ---
scsm-dc01   administrators Administrator        User  contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-500
scsm-dc01   administrators Enterprise Admins    Group contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-519
scsm-dc01   administrators Domain Admins        Group contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-512
scsm-server administrators Administrator        User          S-1-5-21-1473970658-40817565-21663372-500
scsm-server administrators !svcServiceManager   User  contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-1274
scsm-server administrators !svcServiceManagerWF User  contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-1275
scsm-server administrators !svcscoservice       User  contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-1310
scsm-server administrators Domain Admins        Group contoso S-1-5-21-4081441239-4240563405-729182456-512

===================================================================================  

#>
Function Get-LocalGroupMembers
{
param(
[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true)][array]$server = $env:computername,
$GroupName = $null
)
PROCESS {
    $finalresult = @()
    $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server"

    if (!($groupName))
    {
    $Groups = $computer.psbase.Children | Where {$_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq "group"} | select -expand name
    }
    else
    {
    $groups = $groupName
    }
    $CurrentDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().GetDirectoryEntry() | select name,objectsid
    $domain = $currentdomain.name
    $SID=$CurrentDomain.objectsid
    $DomainSID = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid[0], 0)).value


    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
    $gmembers = $null
    $LocalGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$server/$group,group")


    $GMembers = $LocalGroup.psbase.invoke("Members")
    $GMemberProps = @{Server="$server";"Local Group"=$group;Name="";Type="";ADSPath="";Domain="";SID=""}
    $MemberResult = @()


        if ($gmembers)
        {
        foreach ($gmember in $gmembers)
            {
            $membertable = new-object psobject -Property $GMemberProps
            $name = $gmember.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",'GetProperty', $null, $gmember, $null)
            $sid = $gmember.GetType().InvokeMember("objectsid",'GetProperty', $null, $gmember, $null)
            $UserSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid, 0)
            $class = $gmember.GetType().InvokeMember("Class",'GetProperty', $null, $gmember, $null)
            $ads = $gmember.GetType().InvokeMember("adspath",'GetProperty', $null, $gmember, $null)
            $MemberTable.name= "$name"
            $MemberTable.type= "$class"
            $MemberTable.adspath="$ads"
            $membertable.sid=$usersid.value


            if ($userSID -like "$domainsid*")
                {
                $MemberTable.domain = "$domain"
                }

            $MemberResult += $MemberTable
            }

         }
         $finalresult += $MemberResult 
    }
    $finalresult | select server,"local group",name,type,domain,sid
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting any error messages? All you've provided here is a copy/paste of someone else's function.

Comment: Here's another chap trying the exact same problem, without any work. http://superuser.com/questions/847070/powershell-script-to-retrieve-local-group-member-data/847588

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ft` end the script with `export-csv` and the appropriate switches.