# Powershell command regarding AD groups

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

We have a security group, SQL DBA.
I need to know all servers that are part of this group. Is this possible?
I'm a backup admin, just starting to learn AD/Windows, so apologize if its a stupid question.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: This should be a fairly straightforward operation to look-up in the manual.  I'm surprised you didn't find any examples out there.

Comment: Hi XCondE, im not looking for the list of members, but all the servers this group is added as an administrator

Comment: Oh gotcha.  I misinterpreted your question.  If other people can understand it then never mind me :)

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: you want to look for every server, if the SQL DBA-Security group is listed in the local administrators group of the server?

Comment: What type of group is it? Local to the system or is it in Active Directory?

Comment: Poss duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/648506/get-all-local-groups-members-and-account-status-locked-and-disabled
Following the links in that question will get to https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Gather-Local-Group-0d0a85ad which a function for this exact purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell cmdlet `get-adgroupmember` to get the members of a group.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Your Group'
```

Maybe pipe this to `Select-Object Name` for a more human-readable list.

`Get-Command` can be useful for finding commands. You can even filter by powershell module (discoverable via `Get-Module`).

Comment: Hi IsAGuest, im not looking for the list of members, but all the servers this group is added as an administrator.